# Pandas type error trying to plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a basic scatter plot based on a Pandas dataframe. But when I call the scatter routine I get an error "TypeError: invalid type promotion". Sample code to reproduce the problem is shown below:

```
t1 = pd.to_datetime('2015-11-01 00:00:00')
t2 = pd.to_datetime('2015-11-02 00:00:00')

Time = pd.Series([t1, t2])
r = pd.Series([-1, 1])

df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': Time, 'Value': r})
print(df)

print(type(df.Time))
print(type(df.Time[0]))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(x_size,y_size))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(df.Time, y=df.Value, marker='o')
```

The resulting output is

```
        Time  Value
0 2015-11-01     -1
1 2015-11-02      1
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'>

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-285-f4ed0443bf4d> in <module>()
     15 fig = plt.figure(figsize=(x_size,y_size))
     16 ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
---> 17 ax.scatter(df.Time, y=df.Value, marker='o')

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in scatter(self, x,    y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha, linewidths, verts, **kwargs)
   3635             edgecolors = 'face'
   3636 
-> 3637         offsets = np.dstack((x, y))
   3638 
   3639         collection = mcoll.PathCollection(

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\shape_base.py in dstack(tup)
    365 
    366     """
--> 367     return _nx.concatenate([atleast_3d(_m) for _m in tup], 2)
    368 
    369 def _replace_zero_by_x_arrays(sub_arys):

TypeError: invalid type promotion
```

Searching around I've found a similar post [Pandas Series TypeError and ValueError when using datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26126275/pandas-series-typeerror-and-valueerror-when-using-datetime) which suggests that the error is caused by having multiple data types in the series. But that does not appear to be the issue in my example, as evidenced by the type information I'm printing.

Note that if I stop using pandas datetime objects and make the 'Time' a float instead this works fine, e.g.

```
t1 = 1.1 #
t2 = 1.2

Time = pd.Series([t1, t2])
r = pd.Series([-1, 1])

df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': Time, 'Value': r})
print(df)

print(type(df.Time))
print(type(df.Time[0]))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(x_size,y_size))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(df.Time, y=df.Value, marker='o')
```

with output

```
   Time  Value
0   1.1     -1
1   1.2      1
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
```

and the graph looks just fine. I'm at a loss as to why the use of a datetime is causing the invalid type promotion error? I'm using Python 3.4.3 and pandas 0.16.2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks @martinvseticka. I think your assessment is correct based on the numpy code you pointed me to. I was able to simplify your tweaks a bit more (and added a third sample point) to get

```
t1 = pd.to_datetime('2015-11-01 00:00:00')
t2 = pd.to_datetime('2015-11-02 00:00:00')
t3 = pd.to_datetime('2015-11-03 00:00:00')

Time = pd.Series([t1, t2, t3])
r = pd.Series([-1, 1, 0.5])

df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': Time, 'Value': r})

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(x_size,y_size))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot_date(x=df.Time, y=df.Value, marker='o')
```

The key seems to be calling 'plot_date' rather than 'plot'. This seems to inform mapplotlib to not try to concatenate the arrays.

Answer (score 8):

There is another way, that we should drop uses Series.  Just use list for time.

```
t1 = pd.to_datetime('2015-11-01 00:00:00')
t2 = pd.to_datetime('2015-11-02 00:00:00')

Time = pd.Series([t1, t2])
r = pd.Series([-1, 1])

df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': Time, 'Value': r})
print(df)

print(type(df.Time))
print(type(df.Time[0]))
x_size = 800
y_size = 600
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(x_size,y_size))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(list(df.Time.values), list(df.Value.values), marker='o')
```

Comment: your approach works nicely too. I edited it to fix the figure size and removed the explicit calls to list (not necessary).

Comment: This worked nicely for me as well, many thanks. But are lists OK to use? So that Matplotlib doesn't try to modify them?

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.dates as dates

t1 = pd.to_datetime('2015-11-01 00:00:00')
t2 = pd.to_datetime('2015-11-02 00:00:00')

idx = pd.Series([t1, t2])
s = pd.Series([-1, 1], index=idx)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot_date(idx, s, 'v-')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I'm new to Python so hopefully I'm not wrong. Basically, I tried to adapt your example according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/13674286/99256.

The problem with your script is that `numpy` [tries](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/shape_base.py#L317) to concatenate `df.Time`  and `df.Value` series and it can't find a suitable type for the new array because one array is numeric and the second one is composed of `Timestamp` instances.

Comment: Yeah, well, I was looking extensively into the issue and this is really all I know even though it is not a solution per se.

Comment: Thanks @martinvseticka. I was able to update your suggestion a bit (see below). This is certainly non-intuitive behavior - I would have thought the X and Y arrays could be different data types.

Answer (score 5):

`scatter` plots have some properties that cannot be simulated in `plot` or `plot_date` (as the ability to plot markers with varying size).

Converting the Time series of type:`pandas.tslib.Timestamp` to a list of type:`datetime.datetime` before plotting the scatter did the trick for me:

```
times = [d.to_pydatetime() for d in df.Time]]
ax.scatter(times, y=df.Value, marker='o')
```

Answer (score 2):

I've changed the type of datetime column to string in fly:

```
plt.scatter(df['Date'].astype('str'), df['Category'], s=df['count'])
```

and the scatter plot works.
Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like this:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import datetime

    df = pd.DataFrame({"Time":["2015-11-01 00:00:00", "2015-11-02 00:00:00"], "value":[ 1, -1]})
    df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.scatter(np.arange(len(df['Time'])), df['value'], marker='o')
    ax.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(len(df['Time'])))
    ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(df['Time'], rotation=90)
    plt.xlabel("Time")
    plt.ylabel("value")

    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

All the above answers are amazing. But, in my case, the error is fixed by updating the libraries. That you can do by Conda terminal with the command, 
conda update --all