# Matplotlib throwing error when datetime used as x axis

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

When I plot a pandas `dataframe` with a `datetime` as the index, I get a `NonGuiException` error (using iPython notebook):

```
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1000))
ts = ts.cumsum()
ts.plot()
```

[image: Pic of error]

However, if I change the index to an integer, it works:

```
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000), index=range(1000))
ts = ts.cumsum()
ts.plot()
```

[image: Pic of chart]

Comment: Does the `cumsum` work as expected for the `datetime` input? If so, is it possible that the resulting integers are simply too large?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be similar to one I had a week ago. See [Pandas type error trying to plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33676608/pandas-type-error-trying-to-plot/33699453#33699453). I had to change to using `plot_date()` rather than `plot()` in order to get matplotlib to understand that my x-axis was a date.